# Drools rules will not compile because of missing Spring-injected dependencies

Tags: spring, web-services, soap, ant, drools

I am using maven-ant-tasks-2.0.10.jar with build.xml to compile Drools rules.

The rule goes something like this:

```
package example

//list any import classes here.
import example.util.Util;

//declare any global variables here
global example.util.Util util;

rule "Simple rule 1"
  dialect "mvel"
  when
   //conditions
  then
   //actions
   util.handleIssue( "Simple rule 1 executed..." );
end
```

The Util class has a method in the looks like the following:

```
public class Util {
    // Agent is a Spring Injected Dependency.
    private Agent agent;

    public void handleIssue( MyObject mo ) throws JAXBException {           
      try {
        // This is a SOAP call using a WSDL to an external Spring-WS service.
        agent.performTask( "dataneeded" );
      } catch( SoapFaultClientException sfce ) {
        // TODO
      }

    public void agent( Agent agent ) {
     this.agent = agent;
    }
}
```

An error returns in the form of a SoapFaultClientException when attempting to compile the build.xml. Obviously, maven-ant-tasks-2.0.10.jar/drools compiler does not recognize the Spring-Injected dependencies and probably does not even care or know about Spring.

How do I make the dependencies visible to maven-ant-tasks-2.0.10.jar so the drools rules can compile and run properly? Am I abusing the way Drools can be used? Does anyone know how to compile rules with Java Objects that use Spring-Inject dependencies (Spring Web Services)?

When I take out the part calling the web service, it compiles just fine.

Comment: Your report is inconsistent and incomplete. The rule code contains a call to `util.doesPatternExist`, but the error message refers to `util.handleIssue` (although argument lists appear to be the same). But `handleIssue` has only one argument (`MyObject`) and the line after `[Near` quotes a String argument (`"m ...`), which doesn't fit. **Missing: how is `util` declared in the DRL code?**

Comment: I apologize. I don't know what the consequence is of posting the exact code. I would like to re-phrase my inquiry.

Comment: It doesn't have to be the *exact* code (you can change names), but it must be consistent and enough to deduce what might going on. An undeclared object(?) or class(?) or whatever is pointless.

Comment: Thanks for responding, laune. OK, I updated the post hopefully to reflect the general idea.

Comment: Class Util contains the dependency, and Util must also be referenced from your application code, where it creates the Util object and assigns it to the DRL global variable `util`. If you can compile your app without any reference to Drools (should be simple to comment out) and execute and `util.handleIssue()`, I see no reason why it shouldn't work in combination with Drools.

Comment: If I attempted to test this module, it would definitely require me to mock the service calls (using SpringJUnit4ClassRunner, Mockito). Instead of a unit test, it would be an integration test because of the service references.

Comment: Perhaps I should have said that "compiling Drools rules" (i.e., the DRL code) is something where dependency injection doesn't matter. This is a compilation of DRL to a binary form, which can be used - immediately or after serialization and (later) deserialization to create a knowledge base. If you compile separately, no execution takes place, so there isn't any dependency injection. The DRL compiler would see class Util. you have removed the error messages which (IIRC) indicate that util wasn't known to the compiler. What *is* the error?

Comment: compiledrl:
     [echo] Compiling rules package for *.drl
 [compiler] Unable to Analyse Expression //actions
 [compiler]         util.handleIssues( $myObject );
 [compiler]         
 [compiler]   LOG.info( "Rule 1737 executed..." );:
 [compiler] [Error: org/springframework/ws/soap/client/SoapFaultClientException]
 [compiler] [Near : {... util.handleIssue ....}]
 [compiler]                                ^
 [compiler] [Line: 15, Column: 0] : [Rule name='1737: handle error code 009']
 [compiler] Unable to Analyse Expression //actions
 [compiler]         util.handleIssues( $myObject );

Comment: I finally figured it out. The dependency for SoapFaultClientException had to be added to the list of "artifact:dependencies" in the build.xml (spring-ws-core, version 1.5.8). Now it is compiling with no errors. Thanks for your help @laune!